# Missing results from grep call with braces in the params executed from Ruby

Tags: ruby, grep, ubuntu-10.04

I am not getting results back from grep when I call it with a param containing curly braces using Ruby's `` or %x{} expressions.

Say I have these files in an empty directory:

```
$ echo '**hello**' > hello.md
$ echo 'hello' > hello.txt
```

If I only want results matching a single extension, Ruby works as expected:

```
$ grep -rn hello . --include=*.txt
./hello.txt:1:hello

$ grep -rn hello . --include=*.md
./hello.md:1:**hello**

$ irb

ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :001 > `grep -rn hello . --include=*.txt`
=> "./hello.txt:1:hello\n"

ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :002 > %x{grep -rn hello . --include=*.md}
=> "./hello.md:1:**hello**\n" 

ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :003 > exit
```

But if I ask for results matching either extension, using grep's curly brace syntax, no results come up with Ruby:

```
$ grep -rn hello . --include=*.{txt,md}
./hello.txt:1:hello
./hello.md:1:**hello**

$ irb

ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :001 > `grep -rn hello . --include=*.{txt,md}`
=> ""

ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :002 > %x{grep -rn hello . --include=*.{txt,md}}
=> ""
```

Edit: echoing works, but command results are still empty:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 > `echo grep -rn hello . --include=*.{txt,md}`
=> "grep -rn hello . --include=*.{txt,md}\n" 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :005 > `grep -rn hello . --include=*.{txt,md}`
=> ""
```

How can I debug this and see the actual command being executed?  And what's the correct way to execute system commands with curly braces in the params from Ruby?

Comment: I'm on mri 1.9.2 and can confirm that I do not have this problem.  If you run simply `%x{echo a{b,c}d}` or something similar do you see the expected result?  Single backspace escaping the brackets also works for me.

Comment: I originally discovered this weirdness on 1.9.2; edited question with those results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a guess: `%x{}` is using `/bin/sh` which isn't behaving like `/bin/bash` (or your usual shell).

This pattern:

```
*.{txt,md}
```

is expanded by your shell just like all the other file globbing patterns. When you run your command from within `irb`, Ruby is probably using `/bin/sh` to execute the command and on your system, `/bin/sh` behaves like a plain POSIX shell which doesn't understand the `*.{a,b}` globbing syntax.

Try invoking `bash` directly:

```
irb> `bash -c 'grep -rn hello . --include=*.{txt,md}'`
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried escaping your curly brackets i.e `{`->`\{` not being able to check this right now I may be wrong but they may need to be escaped.